# Javascript - setting a cookie and pull into ID

Tags: javascript, cookies

So I have the code below that pulls a 'parameter' from the URL and replaces an ID called 'demo' in my HTML: EXAMPLE: sample.com?demo=test

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam) { 
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1); 
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'); 
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) { 
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('='); 
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) { 
            return sParameterName[1]; 
        } 
    } 
}
var demo = decodeURIComponent(getUrlParameter('demo')); 
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = demo;
```

Then I have the following code which does the same, except it pulls from a cookie

```
function getCookie(c_name) { 
    if (document.cookie.length>0) { 
        c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "="); 
        if (c_start!=-1) { 
            c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1; 
            c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start); 
            if (c_end==-1) 
                c_end=document.cookie.length; 
            var cookieContent = "Welcome back " + unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end)); 
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = cookieContent; 
        } 
    } 
} 
getCookie('demo');
```

What I'd like to do is write something that pulls from the parameter immediately, and if a user comes back to the page without the URL parameter, pull from the cookie. I'm thinking this is some sort of IF statement. But I'm confused on how to mesh these two scripts together to work in sync.

So essentially, IF `demo` is in URL, insert into any ID that = `demo`, if not, look in cookie.
It would also be great if I could add spaces to the parameter. So if the URL: sample.com?demo=this+is+a+test
To have the ID = this is a test

**I've figured this out for the most part. BUT, all ID's called 'demo' become 'undefined' within my HTML document.
My HTML looks like this: Welcome New User**

**So I'd like it to display 'New User' or whatever is displayed in the ID IF there is no parameter or cookie set. Hope this makes sense.**

Comment: My eyes are bleeding. Please format your post correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `innerHTML` assignment in `getCookie`, and have it simply return `cookieContent` when it finds the requested cookie. Then you can test the return values of the functions.

```
var demo = getUrlParameter('demo') || getCookie('demo');
if (demo) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = demo;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm noticing that my spans in my content show up as 'undefined' since its classified in the script above. I don't want the text to show undefined if a user strips the URL. How can I avoid this? <span id="demo">A uniquely identifiable element.</span> So I'd like the text to display that ' A uniquely identifiable element.' unless its declared in the URL or cookie. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Also, if my parameter is: demo=this+is+a+test how can I turn those +'s into spaces within my content/text? I can't have + within my content. Would love to find out how to do this. Appreciate the help. Have a good day!

Comment: It shouldn't show up as `undefined`, because the `if()` should skip the `innerHTML` assignment in that case. Unless you're putting the literal string `"undefined" into the cookie.

Comment: You can use `decodeURIComponent` to convert a URL component like `foo+bar` into `foo bar`

Comment: Thanks :) How does this look? var demo = decodeURIComponent(getUrlParameter('demo').replace(/‌​\+/g, " "));